# Install Jenkins X with Cloudflare on AWS EKS platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, amazon-eks, jenkins-x

I have Cloudflare for DNS provider, how can I install Jenkins X in AWS EKS without move from Cloudflare?

I tried to run with this:

> jx install --provider=eks --domain=eks.love-eks.com

but i get

```
retrying after error:checking health of Jenkins server
```

Do you know if Jenkins X support Cloudflare or only Route53 ?

Thanks :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

this article might help you: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/continuous-delivery-eks-jenkins-x/ which walks you through how to setup your DNS. It uses Route53 but the same principles should apply to any DNS provider - you just need to setup a wildcard DNS route to map to the Network Load Balancer IP addresses

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I use this tutorial but i think because i create from Cloudfront the EKS cluster and not from jx something is wrong with the domain :) 

I will tried to create eks cluster with jx :P thanks